# Transparently manipulating strings inserted into an ostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I'd like to provide an `std::ostream` that may or may not, from the user's point of view, encrypt its contents.

Imagine some random function that uses an `std::ostream&`:

```
void write_stuff( std::ostream& stream ) {
    os << "stuff";
}
```

Whether `stuff` is output in cleartext or is encrypted is dependent on how the `stream` argument was initialized.

I'm thinking about inheriting from `std::basic_streambuf`, but I'm not sure it's the best way to go. I think the ideal scenario is some sort of filter object which is run before the contents are actually output. That way it'd be easy to chain operations, e.g. encrypting and then hex-encoding, which is a benefit that making my own `basic_streambuf` does not seem to give (not easily at least).

Any advices?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I followed the strategy laid out by the accepted answer. I found this article on writing a [custom `streambuf` which performs XOR obfuscation](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2499.htm) to be extremely helpful as a starting point.

Comment: can you share your solution?  Thanks.  By the way, was/is your logger based on Petru Marginean's published in Dr. Dobbs about a month before your post? http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/logging-in-c/201804215

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `streambuf` can be implemented in terms of another arbitrary `streambuf` that's either passed in as an argument to the constructor or set with a special member function.  And that allows you to stack `streambuf` implementations like you were thinking of.

You could even make a manipulator that uses the `ostream`'s `rdbuf` function to get the current `streambuf`, call a function on your `streambuf` that sets the 'stacked' `streambuf`, and then calls `rdbuf` again to replace the `ostream`'s `streambuf` with your own.

```
aes_ctr_streambuf encrypter(key);
zlib_streambuf compressor;
::std::cout << stack_streambuf(encrypter) << stack_streambuf(compressor);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I wish there were an easier way of writing iostreams filters, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to describe in short what you have to do in order to create an [I/O stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) for the new source or sink. Luckily, [Jonathan Turkanis](http://www.coderage.com/turkanis/) and [CodeRage, LLC](http://www.coderage.com/) have created  very nice building blocks with exceptional documentation that can help you save hundreds of hours of research and development of new streams. The library is called [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).

The [second example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/container_sink.html) in documentation exactly shows how to solve your problem.

Also, note that they already have an output stream with zip compression. So maybe you don't even need to write a single line of code.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, Boost.Iostreams did come to mind. I'm trying to do this for a logging module, so I'd rather keep external dependencies to a minimum as to make it easier to add logs to an existing project (it is currently a single header file). If writing my own `streambuf` turns out to be too much of a hassle though, I'll surely look into Boost.Iostreams. Thanks.

Comment: @Pedro d'Aquino: Just in case, you might want to look at `bcp` utility. It extracts parts of the Boost so you can use them in your project and not worry about depending on the whole Boost project. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that what I'm about to suggest is exactly what you need (and its too complicated to be a comment), but have you ever heard of the stream **manipulators** ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int, char**)
{
  int a = 10;
  std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl; //outputs: "a: 10"
  std::cout << "a: " << std::hex << a << std::endl; //outputs: "a: a"
  std::cout << "a: " << std::dec << a << std::endl; //outputs: "a: 10"

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You may indeed use a similar pattern (this matches what you actually call a "filter" object) to somehow change the state of your custom stream object.